# message filter for bot's messages undefined node.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am having a bot set up the beginnings of a game. A human inputs the command of /startbrawl to initiate the setup of the game (creating the deck objects). But the two players need to be identified first. I have a message sent from another command that says "Player A is @[username A]. Player B is @[username B]." in the channel this game is happening in. I want the bot from this new command to look at the first message sent in the channel, which is always the "Player A is etc..." message (and is always sent by the bot) and pull both usernames from it in order to specify for this new command who is player A and who is player B. The code I have most recently (after trying multiple things) is this:

```
if (userInput.startsWith("!startbrawl") === true) {
  message.channel.fetchMessages().then(messages => {
  const botMessages = messages.filter(message => message.author.bot);
    console.log(botMessages.mentions.members.first()) //this will be Player A. I'd repeat same for Player B with .last instead.
  }
}
```

This gives me an error:

> (node:15368) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'first' of undefined.

I have made the last line be `console.log(botMessages)` to get all the info about the messages the filter finds. But trying to extract only part of it gives issues about not being defined, or just a result of undefined with no errors. Either way, something isn't working how I think I need it to.

The only other thing I've debated trying is exporting variables from the command prior to this new command. Player A and Player B are defined in the command used to make the channel that this new command is then used in. However, I've never had luck with exporting variables when I've used it in other instances. I use a command handler, so I'm not sure if that affects how exporting variables works... Which method would work best to set up the card game? I'm a novice in general just figuring things out as I go, so some advice (beyond take a course, look up basics, etc) is greatly appreciated. I've taken an online course for javascript and I work best figuring things out first hand.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: From the error message, `botMessages.mentions.members` is `undefined`. Is `botMessages.mentions` what you expect it to be? Are you referencing if correctly (check spelling, make sure you don't need to use a method instead, etc)?

Comment: I get a console message of just "undefined" when using botMessages.mentions instead. No error message. I'm fairly sure I am referencing everything correctly.

Comment: How is the `botMessages` object structured? Are you indeed meant to access mentions like that? Can you post how you constructed `botMessages`?

Comment: botMessages is a Collection of all the information pertaining to the one message sent in the channel so far by the bot. It prints tons of info to the console. (https://i.gyazo.com/72392e56e93d0e5002e6ad4d63ad377e.png for a look at what it prints) I basically just need the usernames mentioned by the bot (ABBI) in the channel by a previous command that sent the "Player A is [username], Player B is [username]." just so I can keep the decks in reference to players A and B constant between commands. If this seems inefficient, which I think it is, let me know how you'd handle it otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `botMessages` is a collection you wanna get a Message object out of it by doing 
`botMessages.first()`

So try logging something like

```js
botMessages.first().mentions.members.first()
```

Comment: This got me a whole collection titled "GuildMember" (different info than the one I had an image of in OP). Inside all the info it gives, it only indicated one user ID, which was my own as I was listed as Player A in the original bot post it looks like it is pulling the info from. So, it looks like this got me closer, but still gave me way more info than I need or think I asked for.

Comment: Well you can just use `botMessages.first().mentions.members.first().id` to get the ID only

Comment: Perfect! That works. I was tiptoeing around it during my tests before posting this but couldn't quite get it!  Thanks so much!